# What encryption method is used on these passwords?

Tags: php, .net, sql

I am working on a program that needs to know what is used to encrypt passwords in the application Tigerpaw 11. Tigerpaw 11 uses SQL so I can see the encrypted password I am just not sure what particular encryption method is used.

I changed one of the users passwords several times so I had some examples for you guys.

For what it helps this is what I know about the application:
- Ties to MS SQL for all data
- Seems to be written in a .NET language

Samples:

```
123456, 6df7a625c514577b8ce73af649e3c179
MyPassword, ec46ca799923b1a6ffab6b5cb75d059a
CrackIt, b4df19b23f1882e4d0a42e2451443628
```

They seem to have some kind of hash value based on user. For this instance it could be "Tim Way" or 50 amongst other fields.

The end result is I want to be able to do user authentication in PHP against this password.

Comment: Does it give different hash for the same password, but different users?

Comment: Yes. If I give the same password to more than one user I get different results in the table.

Comment: It seems like they use something like the user id for determing the salt. See my answer.

Comment: Then it's not hashing *only* the password, but also something else (a "salt"): that would be either a random-looking string for each user, the username, the user ID, or some other unchanging and user-specific piece of data. If it also uses an application-specific salt, it would be much harder to reproduce outside of the app.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's anything too obvious (the usual suspects can be tried in one go [here](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=MyPassword).)  One of those 50 fields doesn't happen to be called "salt", does it? :)

Answer (score 3):

They are probably not encrypted but hashed, the fact that the 'encrypted passwords' are all the same length should have given you a clue. Common hashing functions are MD5 or SHA1.

Comment: `echo -n "123456" | md5sum` or `sha1sum` gives hashes different than those given.

Answer (score 1):

The passwords are not encrypted, but hashed. Your hashes seem to be hashed with the MD5 hashing function. Probably a secret salt is used to make guessing common passwords harder.

Comment: It seems that way. I may just contact the company and see if the volunteer the information.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that they are using salt in there hash.

Salt is a somewhat secret term used change the hash value.  I doubt they would want to tell you the salt.

you can see the results from many popular hashing algos here

http://www.insidepro.com/hashes.php?lang=eng

Comment: Yes, the salt will be your main issue, along with the possibility of them using a non-trivial-to-guess algorithm (e.g. appending the salt twice to the password, then md5 hashing it three times for a giggle.) If it's an application salt, it'll be hard to find, but it's worth seeing if there happens to be a "salt" column in the user table, or trying the username or email address, which are both commonly-used salts. Usually the salt will be different per-user, and therefore stored *somehow* in the database.

Comment: that website runs a lot of the traditional permutations and I used text searched all of the results and did not find a match for the provided hash.  The best way to solve your problem might be have a second online password. i know it sucks but it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a MD5 hash of the password and user name (and/or user ID, if that exists). Also check if there is something else related to the row in the user database table that might also influence the hash. For example, when setting the same password to the same user produces different hashes then there probably is something like a SALT value (a random value or string that changes with each password update).

Given these values you have to guess how they are being combined. If you're unlucky, then they might even use separators and such.

I'd try with

```
md5($username . $password);
md5($userID . $password);   // assuming there is a numeric user ID too
md5($password . $username);
md5($password . ":" . $username);  // separator example
md5($username . $password . $salt)   // if there is any
```

Any any other combination that comes to your mind. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like md5 hash salted with username and secret key (sha1 is 40 chars long).

Comment: I will test this out! I am still looking for the secret key value somehow within the database of the application. I have also ran a de-compiler on the application in question but it did not reveal anything of use yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is reviving an old thread however as of version 14 encryptions have been converted to AES256
I know this applies to credit card details, Not sure if it applies to passwords, They are likely just a hash as per previous answers.